# How to change the text next to a slider form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in html and js

```js
function slide(){
    let v= document.getElementById("slide_inner");
    document.getElementById("slider").textContent=v.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="slider">
            <label for="slide_inner">0</label><input id="slide_inner" onchange="slide()" type="range" min="0" max="26" value="0" class="slider">
        </form>
```

However, when I try and move the slider, the slider also disappears and the only the value remains. I only want the 0 to be updated to the new slider value. Is there a way I can avoid this?

Comment: I mean… you’re replacing the text content of the entire form with the value you’re setting. If you don’t want to do this, adjust your code so that only the label itself is updated.

Comment: What you want is to edit the text node, textContent will affect all child element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to set the text:

```js
function slide() {
  let v = document.getElementById("slide_inner");
  document.getElementById("slider").querySelectorAll("label")[0].innerHTML = v.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="slider">
  <label for="slide_inner">0</label><input id="slide_inner" onchange="slide()" type="range" min="0" max="26" value="0" class="slider">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works but only if I remove the 0 from between the label tags and place it right after the form tag

Comment: Your question didn't stated that

Comment: I mean your solution doesn't change the value between the label tags. It adds a value between the form tags. I found a way to use it by moving the 0.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check